# Hindi font is not displaying correct hindi words in the created pdf using python reportlab pdf library

Tags: python, django, pdf

I am using on reportlab pdf library in django framework in order to create pdf reports in hindi language.I am getting data from PostgreSql database as mention below format.

```
     waterdate      month year   rivername    stationname    distname
2011-06-22 00:00:00 June  2011      नयार       मरोरा           पौड़ी
2011-06-22 00:00:00 June  2011      गंगा        हरिद्वार          हरिद्वार
2011-06-22 00:00:00 June  2011      गंगा        नरोरा/डी0एस0    बुलन्दशहर
2011-06-22 00:00:00 June  2011      गंगा        फतेहगढ़         फर्रूखाबाद
2011-06-22 00:00:00 June  2011      गंगा        गुमटिया          कन्नौज
```

I have written following code to display above table into pdf file.

**printing.py**

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter,A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate,Paragraph,Table,TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER,TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from .models import Rainfall
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Hindi1', 'gargi.ttf'))

class printReport: 
def rainfall_report(self):
    buffer = self.buffer 
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(self.buffer,rightMargin=10,leftMargin=10,topMargin=25,bottomMargin=25,pagesize=self.pagesize)
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="TableHeader",alignment=TA_CENTER,))
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="ParagraphTitle", fontSize='11',alignment=TA_JUSTIFY,fontName="FreeSansBold"))
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Justify", fontSize='11',alignment=TA_JUSTIFY,fontName="FreeSansBold"))
    data = []
    data.append(Paragraph( 'Rainfall Data', styles['Title']))
    data.append(Spacer(1,12))
    table_data =[]
    table_data.append([
        Paragraph('Date', styles['TableHeader']),
        Paragraph('Month', styles['TableHeader']),
        Paragraph('Year',styles['TableHeader']),
        Paragraph('River Name',styles['TableHeader']),
        Paragraph('Station Name',styles['TableHeader']),
        Paragraph('District Name',styles['TableHeader'])
        ])
    rainfall_data = Rainfall.objects.all()[:10]
    for rainfall in rainfall_data:
        table_data.append([
            rainfall.waterdate,
            rainfall.month,
            rainfall.year,
            rainfall.rivername,
            rainfall.stationname, 
            rainfall.districtname
            ])
    user_table = Table(table_data,colWidths=[doc.width/7.0]*7)
    user_table.hAlign = 'CENTER'
    user_table.setStyle(TableStyle(
        [ ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25 , colors.black),
          ('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1,),0.5, colors.black ),
          ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,0), 'MIDDLE'),
          ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,0), colors.gray ),
          ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,1), (-1,-1), colors.black),
          ('VALIGN',(2,1),(-3,-1),'MIDDLE'),
          ('ALIGN',(0,1),(-1,-1),'CENTRE'),
          ( 'FONT' , (3,0),(-1,-1) , 'Hindi1') ]))
    data.append(user_table)
    doc.build(data)
    pdf=buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    return pdf
```

Above code dispalying data into the pdf file as below.

[image]

As you can see **stationname** and **distname** column hindi words are not dislaying correct as metioned above database table.
For instanse , हरिद्वार word is not dislaying correct in pdf file.

Please help me out to solve this issue. 
Any help would be greate apprications.

Comment: There are very few PDF libraries that are able to make the ligatures when rendering Indic languages. Read [this white paper](https://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Whitepaper_pdfCalligraph_2017.pdf) to understand what is needed if you want to display Hindi, Tamil, Telugu, Kannada,... correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will go through.

Comment: Report lab gave me lot of trouble writing hindi font. So I first converted the text to html then to PDF using pdfkit. It worked nicely for me. So you can also think in that direction.

Answer (score -1):

Your font path is `/usr/local/src/test_project/members/templates/members/` you can register the font in this way:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Hindi1', '/usr/local/src/test_project/members/templates/members/gargi.ttf.ttf'))
```